# Standard "Send an Email" with Attachments

Tags: email, attachment, appexchange

I'm looking for a solution (AppExchange, github...) to select attachments from the list of Attachments when on the standard "Send an Email" page (/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor).

It looks like I can only select from Documents or upload a new Attachment by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Drawloop](http://support.drawloop.com/lds/ddp-help/basic-information/basics) will allow you to select which attachments you want to send, but the catch is you have to send a PDF merge file as part of the email. But if that is what you are doing anyway then Drawloop has some amazing features for attachments including watermarking them.

[Conga](https://www.congasphere.com/FuzeExtract/Using_a_Salesforce_Attachment.htm?Highlight=attach%20from%20attachments) will let you add an attachment via a query, and just send an email, so as long as you can query the attachment, this app is probably better for this one scenario.

If you are sending from cases, [email to case premium](https://docs.internetcreations.com/?id=a1L40000000KpANEA0) will do it also.

Whilst I've personally used all those options, there is also [this](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wGaqEAE) which seems to do the job but it's exy when you can use one of the other apps that also does so much more.

Comment: Are any of those free solutions?

Comment: No, unfortunately. But with Drawloop you can just buy one licence for around $18/user/month if you were going to automate everything. But it's so worth it for everyone to use it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send email for cases, email to case premium will enable option to add attachment, or best option is to use feed based layout for email,or use chatter to send an email to anyone which enables drag and drop options for adding attachments directly by dragging it to email body.

Comment: Thanks, I was just coming back to mention Case Feeds also. Excellent new solution from Salesforce - and part of the standard Case object - you don't even need Service Cloud. Now if only you could use Case Feeds idea for the Contact or custom objects, that would be good.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by send an email to anyone from chatter? Surely that would be send an email to any Salesforce User via chatter. You can't AFAIK send email to the Contact by posting on the Contact record's chatter feed, for example.

Comment: It's not case specific.

Comment: Chatter was mentioned here in sense of chatter- feed based layout for service console, so it is basically (as per salesforce configuration you need chatter enabled in your org to use this) chatter functionality which we can avail when we're using feed based email functionality which you can use for any salesforce sales object (case, lead, opportunity) not just case